# pageload function from jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to trigger some action each time pages with class 'someClass' are loaded. I have found out that there is pageload function in jquery mobile, but i don't know how to use it. i would like it to do something like this:

```
$('.someClass').pageload(function(){
   alert('Hello World');
});
```

Is it the right use of it? or is there any other way to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use a delegate that listens to the pageshow event, like this:

```
$(document).delegate('.someClass', 'pageshow', function() {
//Do something
});
```